# HTMLCalendar in Django app: missing arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying to replicate this [Link](https://uggedal.com/journal/creating-a-flexible-monthly-calendar-in-django/) in my Django app

**Views.py**

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from datetime import date
from itertools import groupby
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape as esc
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class WorkoutCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, workouts):
        super(WorkoutCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.workouts = self.group_by_day(workouts)

    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        if day != 0:
            cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
            if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
                cssclass += ' today'
            if day in self.workouts:
                cssclass += ' filled'
                body = ['<ul>']
                for workout in self.workouts[day]:
                    body.append('<li>')
                    body.append('<a href="%s">' % workout.get_absolute_url())
                    body.append(esc(workout.title))
                    body.append('</a></li>')
                body.append('</ul>')
                return self.day_cell(cssclass, '%d %s' % (day, ''.join(body)))
            return self.day_cell(cssclass, day)
        return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')

    def formatmonth(self, year, month):
        self.year, self.month = year, month
        return super(WorkoutCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

    def group_by_day(self, workouts):
        field = lambda workout: workout.performed_at.day
        return dict(
            [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(workouts, field)]
        )

    def day_cell(self, cssclass, body):
        return '<td class="%s">%s</td>' % (cssclass, body)

def calendar(request, year, month):


  my_workouts = Quiz.objects.orderby('scheduled_date').filter(owner_id=request.user.pk, scheduled_date__year=year, scheduled_date__month=month).annotate(c=Sum('weight')).values('c')

  print("my_workouts", my_workouts)

  cal = WorkoutCalendar(my_workouts).formatmonth(year, month)
  return render_to_response('classroom/teachers/graph_tot_trucks.html', {'calendar': mark_safe(cal),})
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('abc/', teachers.calendar, name='cal'),
```

**foo.html**

```
<head>

    {{calendar}}

</head>
```

When I run this it results in

> calendar() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'year' and 'month'

What is it that I am doing differently than the code provided in the link?

**Traceback**

Traceback:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /shipper/abc/ Exception Value: calendar()
>   missing 2 required positional arguments: 'year' and 'month'

Comment: you need to provide those 2 arguments from your url.py.

Comment: @NalinDobhal That's quite obvious but what do I pass in them ?

Comment: my bad. see one guy answered, you can follow that approach. Then your url structure will be like abc/2019/July, else you can remove those positional arguments and use get params.  In that case your url structure will be abc/?month=July&year=2019 or abc/?month=07&year=2019

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `year` and `months` as parameters in `urls.py`

```
path('abc/<int:year>/<int:month>/', name='cal'),
```

If you want to create a calendar for each year and month, then you will have to loop through each year and each month

```
years = set([quiz.scheduled_date.year for quiz in Quiz.objects.all()])
months = set([quiz.scheduled_date.month for quiz in Quiz.objects.all()])

quizzes = []

for year in years:

    for month in months:

        quiz = Quiz.objects.orderby('scheduled_date').filter(owner_id=request.user.pk, scheduled_date__year=year, scheduled_date__month=month).annotate(c=Sum('weight')).values('c')
        quizzes.append(quiz)
```

Comment: but that would just change the path, won't it ?

Comment: No it does not change the path. It tells Django that the values of `month` and `year` which you defined in `calendar()` will be retrieved from the url (eg: abc/2019/05). Any argument after `request` must be added in `urls.py` otherwise Django will raise an error.

Comment: I changed it to `path('abc/2019/05/', teachers.calendar, name='cal'),` but it still says calendar() missing 2 required positional arguments

Comment: You have to keep it like this : `path('abc/<int:year>/<int:month>/', teachers.calendar, name='cal'),` That was just an example

Comment: It did work but that way I have to specifically open the link everytime I want to see calender of any month. Shouldn't it create a calendar of the month extracted by `Quiz.objects.orderby('scheduled_date').filter(owner_id=request.user.pk, scheduled_date__year=year, scheduled_date__month=month).annotate(c=Sum('weight')).values('c')
`

Comment: @RahulSharma In this case you will have to loop through all months and years. You find an example in my updated answer

Comment: Do I now need to change the URL as well ? also how do I change the `cal = WorkoutCalendar(my_workouts).formatmonth(year, month)` ?

Comment: No you don't need to. The updated answer shows how to extract calendar for every year and every month without using the url, as you previously stated `(but that way I have to specifically open the link everytime I want to see calender of any month)`

Comment: I replaced that specific part and now it says`name 'my_workouts' is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195813/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-amine-messaoudi).